# How to apply conditional parameters on @ParametrizedTest?

Tags: kotlin, junit5

How can I assert conditionally according to my parameter index?

An example of what I would like to do is as follows:

```
@ParametrizedTest
@CsvSource("1, s",    // this is parameter1  (or index 1)
          "2, 4",    // this is parameter2  (or index 2)
          "3, null"  // this is parameter3  (or index 3)
          ) 
fun ConditionalParametersTest(id Int, result String){

if (paramater1 || index = 1) {
 x = method1(parameter1)
 assertEqual(x, parameter1.result)
}
else if (parameter2 || index = 2) {
 x = method2(parameter2)
 assertEqual(x, parameter2.result)
}
else if (parameter3 || index = 3) {
 assertThrows<ExceptionType>{
 method2(parameter3)
 }
}
```

Comment: Having conditionals in a test is a bit of a code smell, and testing two different methods within one test seems especially weird - why not split this up into three tests? You can then parameterise each one as appropriate (e.g. to create multiple cases where method2 throws an exception).

Comment: Ok
Thank you very much for your answer.
How can I vote your answer as the answer? Or how can I vote this as right?

Comment: I posted a comment, not an answer, as it doesn't really answer the question as posed. You need [15+ rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to upvote a comment.